# Org capture templates now take me to org file, not to previous buffer

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

All of a sudden (after changing computer but keeping same settings) my org capture templates take me to the org file where whatever is being captured will be stored, without the need for C-c C-c to save it and return to previous buffer. I have no idea this happened. Below is an example capture template.

To be clear, I want to go into capture, add whatever I want to capture (e.g. a todo item) via C-c C-c, then return to previous work, not be taken to where the todo or whatever it is will be saved.

```
(setq org-capture-templates
     '(("t" "Todo" entry (file "~/Dropbox/org/gtd.org")
         "* TODO %^{Description}\n SCHEDULED: %^{Scheduled}t\n %?\n %i\n %a") 
))
```

**EDIT (more detail):** 
1. I'm taken to a capture buffer. 2. I add the description and press RET. 3. I add the date by selecting and pressing RET. That return takes me to the gtd.org file, rather than leaving me in the capture buffer to do anything else, like add more detail, a deadline etc., then finalise with a C-c C-c and return to previous buffer. This appeared out of nowhere, with no change to my init.el. Is it some sort of conflict with a package update?

Emacs version 26.1 (9.0)
Org version 9.1.9

Comment: Try to reproduce from Emacs -Q, if you don't use the builtin Org, you need to make sure the correct version of Org is used. The Org mailing list is also a good place for asking for help on Org. BTW, don't forget to mention the version of Emacs & Org you're using.

Comment: Thanks. Added versions. Works (in a different way as the templates aren't set up) from emacs -Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a conflict with `org-poly`. I deleted `org-poly` and the issue has gone away.

[This](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/42392/org-capture-is-not-opening-the-capture-buffer?rq=1) post alludes to it and links to the issue [here](https://github.com/polymode/polymode/issues/40).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are calling `org-capture` either with a prefix, or with an argument.
Could that be the issue? How are you capturing? With a personal keybinding?

Anyway, try hitting `M-x` `org-capture` `RET` and see whether it gives the same results.

---

From the documentation (available in emacs with `C-h` `f` `org-capture`):

> When called interactively with a ‘C-u’ prefix argument GOTO, don’t capture anything, just go to the file/headline where the selected template stores its notes.

Also, you'll notice that the function takes an optional argument. So if you call it programmatically like `(org-capture t)`, you'll "go to" the capture entry point, rather than call capture itself:

```
(org-capture &optional GOTO KEYS)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using C-c c to get into org-capture. Same result with M-x org-capture. Running with C-u prefix it just takes me to the headline a couple of steps earlier. i.e. bypasses the 'Description:' and 'Scheduled:' stages in the mini buffer. The issue is that after I enter the date, I get taken directly to my gtd.org file, whereas previously I stayed in an editing buffer and could add further description, deadlines etc, then call C-c C-c to save the note and exit.